# request headers(CSRF) missing in wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, wkwebview

We are trying to open our app url in `wkwebview` which used to work fine in `uiwebview`.

Our app  is based on `angular2` and `nodejs` and validate csrf header, this flows works with `uiwebview` but same  is not working in `wkwebview` as `x-xsrf-token` is missing from request headers.

Not sure what might be going wrong here

Below is the difference in request header

[image]

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @rckoenes : Nope. I used uiwebview instead of wkwebview

Comment: we are having the same issue .. anyone managed to fix it ?